# Spreading div hight equally depending on their parent div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there's a way to dynamically set a height for divs as a function of their parent div height.

For example, if the user input for the parent div is 100px and it has 4 divs inside - each of the divs will get the height of 25px.

I want to do it dynamically and to make sure the divs spread all over their parent's div height (I tried doing that with JS, but since there is no such a thing 'a fraction of a pixel' - the div height won't correspond to the parent div height in some cases)

Comment: What browser compatibility are you gunning for? If you're not too concerned about that, I would suggest using CSS flexbox. Saves you from all the trouble of listening to window resize and DOM insertion events (if they ever happen) in a JS-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ff0000;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
}
.parent .child {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #00ff00;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/mLLa2xhb/).

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition No 1**

There is a way, here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmvfjc5x/2/) and here's how:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fourth"></div>
    <div class="fourth"></div>
    <div class="fourth"></div>
    <div class="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.fourth {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    background: red;
}
```

However, this is limited, becouse you no longer can use padding in those elements (if you wish to do so) plus height of your div must be equal to its width, since the hight of children is calculated based on the width.

**Proposition No 2**

Using `tables`. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3krv2Lpt/)

HTML:

```
<table class="parent">
    <tr class="fourth">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fourth">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fourth">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fourth">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background: #aaa;
}

.fourth {
    background: red;
}
```

In this case your elements will be automatically, evenly distributed throughout an entire height of your parent div.

Other than that, JS soltion is what you can use but you will need to monitor yourself for changes if they are made and call some sort of update method.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how you could solve this problem using jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/rvna1Lj5/)

```
var parent_height = $('.parent').height();
$('.parent div').height(parent_height / 4);

$('#parent-div-height').keyup(function(event) {
    value = $(this).val();

    $('.parent div').height(value / 4);
});
```

Comment: Ok, but what happens if the parent size is 103px? where would the 3 extra px go?

Comment: if you take a look at dev tools, you will see that each child get 25.75 px, when the parent height is 103px, browser are very good at dealing with floats, so this is you should not be woried about, just do your division and the browser engine will take care of it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `table` layout `display:table` and `display:table-row` for `children`

```css
.parent {
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:20px;
}
.parent .child {
    display: table-row;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">test</div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">test</div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
    <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done in javascript and is dynamic. http://jsfiddle.net/xfx2r741/1/

```
function setHeightSubs () {

    var giveHeight = document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;
    var subs = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
    var subsheight = giveHeight / subs.length;

    for (i=0; i<subs.length; i++) {
          subs[i].style.height = subsheight + "px";
    }

}

setHeightSubs();
```